# Ngx Paginate with offset from API Angular 2

Tags: angular, ngx-pagination

I am making some application for Marvel API

https://developer.marvel.com/

The request is to show list of characters from Marvel API, that only returns 20 of results, i can limit only 100 of items, but there are more than 1500 items. It means that i need to create pagination in angular with offset on ngx-paginate. I have used pagination when i can get all items form api, ngx-paginate will than do it easy, but when i have so many results that i have never user server side pagination. This is what i have for now without offset and only first 20 results.

**app,module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Ng2SearchPipeModule } from 'ng2-search-filter';
import { Ng2OrderModule } from 'ng2-order-pipe';
import { Md5 } from 'ts-md5/dist/md5';
import { CharactersService } from './characters/characters.service';
import { NgxPaginationModule } from 'ngx-pagination';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { CharactersListComponent } from './characters/characters-list/characters-list.component';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        CharactersListComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        Ng2SearchPipeModule,
        Ng2OrderModule,
        NgxPaginationModule,
    ],
    providers: [CharactersService, Md5],
    schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**characters.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Md5 } from 'ts-md5/dist/md5';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class CharactersService {
    private _marvelCharacterUrl: string = "https://gateway.marvel.com:443/v1/public/characters";
    private _publicKey: string = "c4b5296bc35888971631d22848916410";
    private _privateKey: string = "fddd97e16368b2fee706a1f6de69f30f191467d3";
    constructor(private _httpService: HttpClient, private _md5: Md5) { }
    private getHash(timeStamp: string): string {
        let hashGenerator: Md5 = new Md5();
        hashGenerator.appendStr(timeStamp);
        hashGenerator.appendStr(this._privateKey);
        hashGenerator.appendStr(this._publicKey);
        let hash: string = hashGenerator.end().toString();
        return hash;
    }
    private getTimeStamp(): string {
        return new Date().valueOf().toString();
    }    
    getAllCharacters() {
        let timeStamp = this.getTimeStamp();
        let hash = this.getHash(timeStamp);
        let requestUrl = this._marvelCharacterUrl + "?orderBy=name" + "&ts=" + timeStamp + "&apikey=" + this._publicKey + "&hash=" + hash;
        return this._httpService.get(requestUrl);
    }

    getCharacterByName(name: string) {
        let timeStamp = this.getTimeStamp();
        let hash = this.getHash(timeStamp);
        let requestUrl = this._marvelCharacterUrl + "?orderBy=name" + "&nameStartsWith=" + name + "&ts=" + timeStamp + "&apikey=" + this._publicKey + "&hash=" + hash;
        return this._httpService.get(requestUrl);
    }

}
```

**characters-list.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { CharactersService } from '../characters.service';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-characters-list',
    templateUrl: './characters-list.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./characters-list.component.css']
})
export class CharactersListComponent implements OnInit {
    private characters: any = [];

    constructor(private charactersService: CharactersService, private router: Router,
        private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute ) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.getCharacters();
}

private getCharacters(){
    this.charactersService.getAllCharacters()
        .subscribe(characters => {
            this.characters = characters;    
        });
}
    private getCharactersSearch(query: string) {
        this.charactersService.getCharacterByName(query)
            .subscribe(characters => {
                this.characters = characters;
            });
    }
}
```

**characters-list.component.html**

```
<header>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Application</a>
  </nav>
</header>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <nav class="navbar">
       <input class="form-control" type="text" name="search" #searchTerm  (keyup)="searchTerm.value.length ? getCharactersSearch(searchTerm.value) : getCharacters()">
    </nav>
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>#</th>
          <th>Name
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let character of characters.data.results | orderBy: key : reverse | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 10, currentPage: p }">
          <td>{{character.id}}</td>
          <td>{{character.name}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <pagination-controls (pageChange)="p = $event"></pagination-controls>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is how JSON looks like

```
{
  "code": 200,
  "status": "Ok",
  "copyright": "© 2018 MARVEL",
  "attributionText": "Data provided by Marvel. © 2018 MARVEL",
  "attributionHTML": "<a href=\"http://marvel.com\">Data provided by Marvel. © 2018 MARVEL</a>",
  "etag": "6bfc6364f1872b951cf3f51b95a38dc002c11830",
  "data": {
    "offset": 0,
    "limit": 1,
    "total": 1491,
    "count": 1,
    "results": [
      {
        "id": 1011334,
        "name": "3-D Man",
        "description": "",
        "modified": "2014-04-29T14:18:17-0400",
        "thumbnail": {
          "path": "http://i.annihil.us/u/prod/marvel/i/mg/c/e0/535fecbbb9784",
          "extension": "jpg"
        },
        "resourceURI": "http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/characters/1011334",
        "comics": {
          "available": 12,
          "collectionURI": "http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/characters/1011334/comics",
          "items": [
            {
              "resourceURI": "http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/comics/21366",
              "name": "Avengers: The Initiative (2007) #14"
            },
            {
              "resourceURI": "http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/comics/24571",
              "name": "Avengers: The Initiative (2007) #14 (SPOTLIGHT VARIANT)"
            },
            {
              "resourceURI": "http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/comics/21546",
              "name": "Avengers: The Initiative (2007) #15"
            },
            {
              "resourceURI": "http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/comics/21741",
              "name": "Avengers: The Initiative (2007) #16"
            },
            {
              "resourceURI": "http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/comics/21975",
              "name": "Avengers: The Initiative (2007) #17"
            },
            {
              "resourceURI": "http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/comics/22299",
              "name": "Avengers: The Initiative (2007) #18"
            },
            {
              "resourceURI": "http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/comics/22300",
              "name": "Avengers: The Initiative (2007) #18 (ZOMBIE VARIANT)"
            },
            {
              "resourceURI": "http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/comics/22506",
              "name": "Avengers: The Initiative (2007) #19"
            },
            {
              "resourceURI": "http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/comics/8500",
              "name": "Deadpool (1997) #44"
            },
            {
              "resourceURI": "http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/comics/10223",
              "name": "Marvel Premiere (1972) #35"
            },
            {
              "resourceURI": "http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/comics/10224",
              "name": "Marvel Premiere (1972) #36"
            },
            {
              "resourceURI": "http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/comics/10225",
              "name": "Marvel Premiere (1972) #37"
            }
          ],
          "returned": 12
        },
        "series": {
          "available": 3,
          "collectionURI": "http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/characters/1011334/series",
          "items": [
            {
              "resourceURI": "http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/series/1945",
              "name": "Avengers: The Initiative (2007 - 2010)"
            },
            {
              "resourceURI": "http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/series/2005",
              "name": "Deadpool (1997 - 2002)"
            },
            {
              "resourceURI": "http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/series/2045",
              "name": "Marvel Premiere (1972 - 1981)"
            }
          ],
          "returned": 3
        },
        "stories": {
          "available": 21,
          "collectionURI": "http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/characters/1011334/stories",
          "items": [
            {
              "resourceURI": "http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/stories/19947",
              "name": "Cover #19947",
              "type": "cover"
            },
            {
              "resourceURI": "http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/stories/19948",
              "name": "The 3-D Man!",
              "type": "interiorStory"
            },
            {
              "resourceURI": "http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/stories/19949",
              "name": "Cover #19949",
              "type": "cover"
            },
            {
              "resourceURI": "http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/stories/19950",
              "name": "The Devil's Music!",
              "type": "interiorStory"
            },
            {
              "resourceURI": "http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/stories/19951",
              "name": "Cover #19951",
              "type": "cover"
            },
            {
              "resourceURI": "http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/stories/19952",
              "name": "Code-Name:  The Cold Warrior!",
              "type": "interiorStory"
            },
            {
              "resourceURI": "http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/stories/47184",
              "name": "AVENGERS: THE INITIATIVE (2007) #14",
              "type": "cover"
            },
            {
              "resourceURI": "http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/stories/47185",
              "name": "Avengers: The Initiative (2007) #14 - Int",
              "type": "interiorStory"
            },
            {
              "resourceURI": "http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/stories/47498",
              "name": "AVENGERS: THE INITIATIVE (2007) #15",
              "type": "cover"
            },
            {
              "resourceURI": "http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/stories/47499",
              "name": "Avengers: The Initiative (2007) #15 - Int",
              "type": "interiorStory"
            },
            {
              "resourceURI": "http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/stories/47792",
              "name": "AVENGERS: THE INITIATIVE (2007) #16",
              "type": "cover"
            },
            {
              "resourceURI": "http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/stories/47793",
              "name": "Avengers: The Initiative (2007) #16 - Int",
              "type": "interiorStory"
            },
            {
              "resourceURI": "http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/stories/48361",
              "name": "AVENGERS: THE INITIATIVE (2007) #17",
              "type": "cover"
            },
            {
              "resourceURI": "http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/stories/48362",
              "name": "Avengers: The Initiative (2007) #17 - Int",
              "type": "interiorStory"
            },
            {
              "resourceURI": "http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/stories/49103",
              "name": "AVENGERS: THE INITIATIVE (2007) #18",
              "type": "cover"
            },
            {
              "resourceURI": "http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/stories/49104",
              "name": "Avengers: The Initiative (2007) #18 - Int",
              "type": "interiorStory"
            },
            {
              "resourceURI": "http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/stories/49106",
              "name": "Avengers: The Initiative (2007) #18, Zombie Variant - Int",
              "type": "interiorStory"
            },
            {
              "resourceURI": "http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/stories/49888",
              "name": "AVENGERS: THE INITIATIVE (2007) #19",
              "type": "cover"
            },
            {
              "resourceURI": "http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/stories/49889",
              "name": "Avengers: The Initiative (2007) #19 - Int",
              "type": "interiorStory"
            },
            {
              "resourceURI": "http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/stories/54371",
              "name": "Avengers: The Initiative (2007) #14, Spotlight Variant - Int",
              "type": "interiorStory"
            }
          ],
          "returned": 20
        },
        "events": {
          "available": 1,
          "collectionURI": "http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/characters/1011334/events",
          "items": [
            {
              "resourceURI": "http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/events/269",
              "name": "Secret Invasion"
            }
          ],
          "returned": 1
        },
        "urls": [
          {
            "type": "detail",
            "url": "http://marvel.com/characters/74/3-d_man?utm_campaign=apiRef&utm_source=0ed81a42460476df2ee6d83540bfbd8c"
          },
          {
            "type": "wiki",
            "url": "http://marvel.com/universe/3-D_Man_(Chandler)?utm_campaign=apiRef&utm_source=0ed81a42460476df2ee6d83540bfbd8c"
          },
          {
            "type": "comiclink",
            "url": "http://marvel.com/comics/characters/1011334/3-d_man?utm_campaign=apiRef&utm_source=0ed81a42460476df2ee6d83540bfbd8c"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I have limit here for 1 that you can have a better look

Comment: correct me if i'm wrong. In one api hit you just get 20 records and in order to get more you need to again hit the api. So you need to handle the server side pagination? m i right?

Comment: Yes, thats correct, but api has value offset that i can say 20, and than he will take from 21 on page 2

Comment: offset   
Skip the specified number of resources in the result set.  query  int

Comment: `pageChange(pageState: PageState)` this function is where you need to hit the api again for next page and pass the offset as `(currentPage-1)*pageSize`

Comment: Can you write and answer i dont know where

Comment: have posted a answer please try this out and let me know if you face any issues.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163725/discussion-between-miomir-dancevic-and-manish).